# Not showing textures when running app at the mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm doing a game, and first it shows a simple menu with some text and an image at the background. Its drawable is R.drawable.background. When I run the application through the emulator it works fine, but when I run it through the mobile in USB debugging mode, the images won't appear, just a black background.
Anyone knows why is it happening?

Comment: Did you possibly put the images in res/drawable-hdpi and then try to run the app on a low or medium dpi device? Those resources will be ignored on that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found exactly what the problem was and the solution.

I finally found that the error was OpenGL related: "glError 1281", what means that the hardware device doesn't support textures whose sizes are not power of two.
I've changed the textures so that they are power-of-two sized (2-4-8-16-32-64-128-etc) and now it works on my mobile too.

Hope it could help somebody with this problem.